# Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool log says it can't do all required actions. Should I be concerned?

Tags: windows-7, malware-removal

Here's what the log file `c:/Windows/debug/mrt.log` of my Windows 7 install says:

```
WARNING: Security policy doesn't allow for all actions MSRT may require.
->Scan ERROR: resource process://pid:6080 (code 0x00000005 (5))
->Scan ERROR: resource process://pid:5300 (code 0x00000057 (87))
->Scan ERROR: resource process://pid:3512 (code 0x00000057 (87))
```

I use the default setup. I didn't change anything. This is the first time I checked the log file and this warning is in there from the start.

Can I do something about it? Or I shouldn't be concerned, because it can do everything what's necessary  anyway? Do you have this warning in your logfile?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it as Administrator. You'll notice a lot of security applications have no problem scanning and finding malicious software, sometimes it just can't remove it as it doesn't have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you think you are Infected

Follow the order given below to properly disinfect your PC

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.